# Trying to add bootstrap refrence in jsx file in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

i'm trying to add bootstrap refrence in jsx file in asp.net mvc.But not getting successful.
index.cshtml

```
 <body class="signup-page">
<script src="~/Assets/JS/react.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/JS/Tutorial.jsx")"></script>
</body>
```

Tutorial.jsx
In this jsx file in render section some bootstrap class is there

```
 render() {
        return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <div class="card card-signup" id="signup">
           <div class="header header-primary text-center">
</div></div></div></div></div>
</form>
```

and i want to add refrence of bootstrap cdn in it but how to achieve it.any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you ‘npm install —save bootstrap’ or ‘yarn add bootstrap’??  Also need to ‘import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';’ on your index.js file

Comment: yes i install react from npm ,Actually my requirement is very simple i am rendering some html in reactjs where some html element uses bootstrap class .now i want to add cdn file .in that reactjsx file so that all bootstrap classes get its link

Comment: You need to install bootstrap and then import it into you index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Just installing React does not install bootstrap.  Look at the dependencies object in your package.json file.  If bootstrap isn’t listed, then it isn’t installed.  Install instructions are in my post above.